# IP webcam stream delay with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ip, webcam, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to use an unused smartphone as a webcam utilizing v4l2 and ffmpeg. The video is provided in mjpeg format and I forward it to /dev/video2 in the following way:

`ffmpeg -re -i http://192.168.178.43:8080/video -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2`

This works as expected, however, it introduces a significant delay to the video, compared to accessing /video directly in a browser.
Interestingly opening the stream via vlc introduces the same delay which may or may not be important in case that vlc uses ffmpeg for that feature.

What causes this delay and are there options to circumvent it?